# TCP: send a data of 'unsigned int' type from a server to a client which receives this data in a 'float' type?

Tags: c#, c, tcp, tcpclient

I know this question is stupid, but I have to solve it.

I have a server (written in C) which send a data of `unsigned int` type. Then I have another client (application written in C#) which receives this data, but MUST stores in a variable with data of `float` type.

I cannot change the source code of the server, so I cannot change `unsigned int` to `float` before sending it to the client.

How can i send a data of `unsigned int` type from a server to a client which receives this data in a `float` type?

I tried to do that, but at the client, the data after transferred is random invalid number (garbage number).

Comment: `unsigned int` and `float` are language types. What is your server actually transmitting "on the wire" in terms of bytes? What does your `C#` application receive, in terms of bytes? Then, please provide some example values. If the server holds a value of 10, and transmits it, what do you want your client to interpret that as?

Comment: Are you sure this is `unsigned int`? Or is it `uint16_t` or `uint32_t`? Will the number of bytes transmitted change depending on the server's architecture? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types

Comment: "I tried to do that, but at the client, the data after transferred is random invalid number (garbage number)." please show what you tried. That helps us better understand where you're at in your understanding.

Comment: I guess byte order is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

At least as far as I can see, you basically have three possibilities:

[image]

The first is the one you've already rejected--converting from int to float in the server.

The second moves that to the client instead--the part of the code that actually reads the data from the wire receives the data in the format it was sent, converts it to floating point as expected by the rest of the client code, then gives it to the client to process.

If you can't make changes to either the client or the server, the third possibility might work. This would be a separate little (tiny) server. The client connects to that server and asks to read a float. It, in turn, connects to the "real" server and asks it for an int. When it receives the reply from the server, it converts that data from integer to floating point then sends that result on to the client.

Of course, for any of these you need to agree on the *precise* format that will be used for the data in each connection. It's not just going to be `int`, but something reasonably complete and precise like: "32-bit unsigned integer transmitted as four consecutive octets in big-endian ordering". In the third case, you basically need to do that twice, once for each connection.